# issue with dhcp default network file

Tags: firewall, dhcp, default

I'm installing dhcp server on Firewall and under that firewall i setup two clients who ll get dynamic ip addresses.

I give static ip address to eth1 port on which i'm installing dhcp server on firewall. I disable firewall. The problem is that, after installing the dhcp server " sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server". and when i open "sudo nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server" file there is nothing in it. Don't know why file is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your question. But I guess you have a problem with an empty file, `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`. This file isn't necessary to run the dhcp server, for example on my dhcp server there is content in this file, but it is all commented out and it works fine. Since you haven't configured anything, I would try to reinstall (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall isc-dhcp-server`) the dhcp server just in case.

But since this should be a non issue in default configs, maybe you simply want to configure your dhcp server? That is done in the file `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`. There you can set up network ranges, static ips over dhcp for your clients and well, anything that needs to be set in the dhcp server. There are a few examples here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server

Comment: thanksbut I'm confused how do I set the interface for dhcp server static ip address ??

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question, at least I don't understand it.

Comment: i sorted out this problem

Comment: thnkx for you help